# Adding opacity to SASS text-shadow

Tags: css, sass

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f5pt0pys/

I am trying to add opacity to the text-shadow. I've tried

```
//color vars
$color-bg: rgba(74,56,158, 0.5);
$color-title: #ffffff;
$color-line-1: rgba(92,196,191, 0.5);
```

but  it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your code works properly and generates as lot of shadows for element. But since you're using multiple semi-transparent shadows - they're forming non-transparent shadow because their **overall** opacity is far more then 1.0

Jsfiddle doesn't seem to display it right, so I've copied your code to [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/FlyingDR/pen/jYyqWP).

A fact that your shadows are semi-transparent can be seen in a case if you'll zoom in your page so your shadows start to cover more then 1px:

[image: Zoomed in shadows]

Alternatively you can use larger step between shadows for test purposes: `$length: $length - 10;`. In this case it will be clear that your shadows are in fact semi-transparent:

[image: Shadows with larger step]

Of course I also need to tell that drawing a lot of complex and semi-transparent shadows will cost browser a lot of resources so you need to use such effect with care since it can cause performance degradation, especially on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
text-shadow: 
1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.50), 
2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.49), 
3px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.48), 
4px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.47), 
5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.46), 
6px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.45), 
7px 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.44), 
8px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.43) 
[...and so on to about 50]
```